# Play store not showing my apps on Android 2.3.6

Tags: android, google-play

I just realized a number of my apps do not show up on Google Play store on OS 2.3.6. I have this Samsung Galaxy Y with 2.3.6.

For example this Speedometer app:
https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.valueapps.utilities.speedometer

When accessed on the above mentioned device, Play store says the device isn't compatible.

[image]

What factors make your app disappear from a particular phone's Play store?

I've installed the app directly on this phone using USB cable+eclipse ( dev environment) and it works just fine. It's not compatibility issue for sure.

Comment: Do you have set any screen size compliance in Manifest ? Do you have disabled any device on the Google Play Developer Console ?

Comment: Any news on the issue?

Answer (score -1):

If your phone will not let you download apps on google play then download an online apk of an older version of the app.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).